# Load Add-In faster on cold boot

Tags: .net, vsto

We are creating an add-in for Microsoft Word (2007 & 2010). We are facing delay issue when we start our add-in on a cold boot meaning the machine is shutdown and started back. Then the first launch of Word takes around 30-35 seconds. Subsequent launches are faster.

We thought that this might be caused by the delay in loading the VSTO and .NET dlls from disk to memory. To test this, we created a dummy Word add-in which contained no code at all. On a cold boot, with only this add-in loaded, Word took around 17 seconds to launch.

Can we somehow speed up this process? If there are any techniques which can make VSTO and .NET dlls load faster, it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does your add-in have lots of external dependencies? Is there much of your code being run that could be put on a background thread?

Answer (score 2):

> To test this, we created a dummy Word add-in which contained no code at all.

This is not a valid test of your theory. Even an add-in that contains no code at all requires the .NET Framework support DLLs to be loaded.

When you add in the *additional* dependencies of your actual add-in, that explains why you see a doubling in the load time required (from 17 to 35 seconds).

This is a known "problem" with .NET solutions—if the .NET runtime environment has not already been loaded, they're relatively slow to start up the first time. The subsequent startup time is much faster.

There's not really much you can do about this, other than [running NGEN over your assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163808.aspx). That might help cold start times a little, but it has other consequences and so I wouldn't recommend it as a simple matter of course. My recommendation would simply be to get used to slow cold starts or switch to a different technology.

Comment: Yes, we do have a lot of code on startup. We are trying to find techniques to speed it up. My point was how to make this 17 seconds of just loading .NET dlls load disappear. Maybe create a dummy .net app and put it it Startup. But this seems to be just diverting the attention from our add-in and also some may call it evil. :)

Comment: @Mayank That's the point, you can't. The .NET Framework has to be loaded first before you can use it. That takes a while on cold boot, but it only has to happen once. This isn't something you can "fix". If it's unacceptable for your use, you'll need to switch technologies. Yes, a dummy app running at startup is the definition of evil.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We are not in a position to switch technologies at this point in time. So I guess we just have to live with the delay (or go evil).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 registry keys that can affect your add-in's load time: `LoadBehavior` and `Warmup`. Read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx).

Set LoadBehavior to 9 (Load on demand) so that your add-in loads when it is first used rather than when Word starts, thereby reducing Word's startup time.

Setting Warmup to 1 might help. This will cause the .NET framework and VSTO runtime to load before your add-in to "reduce the perceived time to load an add-in". (Personally I'm not sure how much of an effect this has. My add-in loads really fast anyway so I didn't see a boost from using this setting.)

Overall it is strange that your add-in takes so long to load. I suggest taking a careful look at the code that runs when your add-in is loaded (constructors, Load events, etc).

Comment: Be careful when changing the LoadBehavior! Recently my add-ins have stopped working when using "Load on demand". Changing it back to "Load at startup" fixed the problem. I'm not sure if this is due to a recent Office update or not.